# ovm printer casting error

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I wanted to print out a structure used in a ovm_sequence_item. Since the structure is long, I plan to override table printer knobs by using tbl_printer.knobs.value_width = 100;

Here is the code snipper

```
   virtual function void do_print(ovm_printer printer);
     ovm_table_printer tbl_printer;
     super.do_print(printer);  //print all other fields
     $cast(tbl_printer, printer);
     tbl_printer.knobs.value_width = 100;
     tbl_printer.print_generic("ppid","CppPpid_t",$bits(CppPpid_t),
                                  $psprintf("A=%0b,B=%0b,C=%0d,D=%0d,E=%0d,F=%0x",
                                               struct.A,
                                               struct.B,
                                               struct.C,
                                               struct.D,
                                               struct.E,
                                               struct.F)
                               );
   endfunction: do_print
```

I am getting this casting error.
Error-[DCF] Dynamic cast failed
*.sv, 58
  Casting of source class type 'SIP_SHARED_LIB.ovm_pkg.ovm_tree_printer' to 
  destination class type 'SIP_SHARED_LIB.ovm_pkg.ovm_table_printer' failed due
  to type mismatch.
  Please ensure matching types for dynamic cast

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong? How is it getting ovm_tree_printer when I am trying to use ovm_printer?

Comment: probably because your 'printer' is not an instance of the 'ovm_table_pribnter'. You can only cast to a base class.

Answer (score 0):

`ovm_printer` is just the base class that declares the API for printers. What gets passed around are concrete classes, like `ovm_table_printer` or `ovm_tree_printer`. Both of these can be stored in a variable of type `ovm_printer`.

You're probably passing a tree printer in the `print(...)` call on your object. If you don't specify any printer, the default printer is used. Per default, this is the table printer, but it could be that this was changed. Look for `ovm_default_printer` in the package scope.

If someone explicitly wants you to do a tree print, then you can't magically change that to a table print. Best you can do is check if you're doing a table print and if so then change the knobs:

```
 if (!$cast(tbl_printer, printer))
   return;
 tbl_printer.knobs.value_width = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks Tudor. You are right. ovm_tree_printer is being passed down as print function argument. I have two questions? How is it printing in table manner still? How to change the table printer knobs without getting the casting error in do_print?

Comment: @user1978273 If someone explicitly wants you to do a tree print, then you can't magically change that to a table print. Best you can do is check if you're doing a table print and if so then change the knobs.